# how to convert geojson to shapely polygon?

Tags: python, pandas, geojson, shapely

i have a geoJSON

```
geo = {'type': 'Polygon',
 'coordinates': [[[23.08437310100004, 53.15448536100007],
   [23.08459767900007, 53.15448536100007],
   [23.08594514600003, 53.153587050000056],
   (...)
   [23.08437310100004, 53.15448536100007]]]}
```

and i want to use these coordinates as an input to `shapely.geometry.Polygon`. The problem is that Polygon only accepts `tuple` values, meaning i have to convert this geojson to a polygon.  When i try to input this type of data into a Polygon there's an error `ValueError: A LinearRing must have at least 3 coordinate tuples`

I tried this:

```
[tuple(l) for l in geo['coordinates']]
```

but this dosen't quite work since it only returns this

```
[([23.08437310100004, 53.15448536100007],
  [23.08459767900007, 53.15448536100007],
  (...)
  [23.08437310100004, 53.15448536100007])]
```

and what i need is this (i think it's a tuple)

```
([(23.08437310100004, 53.15448536100007),
  (23.08459767900007, 53.15448536100007),
  (...)
  (23.08437310100004, 53.15448536100007)])
```

is there a function for this?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

A generic solution is to use the `shape` function. This works for all geometries not just polygons.

```
from shapely.geometry import shape
from shapely.geometry.polygon import Polygon

geo: dict = {'type': 'Polygon',
   'coordinates': [[[23.08437310100004, 53.15448536100007],
   [23.08459767900007, 53.15448536100007],
   [23.08594514600003, 53.153587050000056],
   [23.08437310100004, 53.15448536100007]]]}
polygon: Polygon = shape(geo)
```

Comment: Really good answer here!

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: it doesnt work!

Comment: any details on why its not working?

Answer (score 4):

Try this,

```py
from itertools import chain


geom = {...}
polygon = Polygon(list(chain(*geom['coordinates']))
```

Comment: This method should be more accurate I think, because in other answers only first polygon is taken into account, so if a polygon has an inner ring, it will not show up.

Answer (score 2):

```
from shapely.geometry import Polygon
geo = {'type': 'Polygon',
 'coordinates': [[[23.08437310100004, 53.15448536100007],
   [23.08459767900007, 53.15448536100007],
   [23.08594514600003, 53.153587050000056],
   [23.08437310100004, 53.15448536100007]]]}
Polygon([tuple(l) for l in geo['coordinates'][0]])
```